# Как правильно работать с SSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, sse

```
@Controller
public class BankController extends BaseController {

    private Map<String, ResponseBodyEmitter> emitters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // call inside some method
    /*
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            activateEmitter(dto.getRecipient(), dto.getAmount());
        });
    */

    @GetMapping(path = "/bills/notify")
    public ResponseBodyEmitter registerEmitter(HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        String phone = authentication().getName();
        ResponseBodyEmitter emitter;
        if(emitters.containsKey(phone)) {
            emitter = emitters.get(phone);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
        else {
            emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter(0L);
            emitters.putIfAbsent(phone, emitter);               
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
        }       
        emitter.onCompletion(()-> emitters.remove(phone, emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(()-> emitters.remove(phone, emitter));
        emitter.onError((e)-> emitters.remove(phone, emitter));
        return emitter;
    }
    private void activateEmitter(int id, double amount) {

        BillResponse bill = billService.getBillDTO(id);
        String phone = bill.getOwner().getPhone();
        
        if(emitters.containsKey(phone)) {
            ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = emitters.get(phone);
            try {
                String load = mapper.writeValueAsString(new EmitterPayload(id, amount));
                emitter.send(load);
//              emitter.complete();
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                log.warn(exc.getMessage(), exc);
                emitter.completeWithError(exc);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function connect(){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/bankdemo/bills/notify');
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
/*          
                let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                let cell = '#balance'+json.id;
                let total = parseFloat($(cell).html(), 2) + json.income;
                $(cell).text(total.toFixed(2));
                alert('+ ' + json.income);
                connect();
*/
            }
            else {
                alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status + ', ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status + ', ' + xhr.statusText);
        };
        xhr.onprogress = function() {
            let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            let cell = '#balance'+json.id;
            let total = parseFloat($(cell).html(), 2) + json.income;
            $(cell).text(total.toFixed(2));
            alert('+ ' + json.income);
            xhr.abort();
            connect();
        };
    };
    (function(){
        connect();
    })();

    $(window).on("beforeunload", function(){
        xhr.abort();
    });
    
});
```

Суть проблемы: после получения разовой порции данных с бэка на фронт приходится делать реконнект, причём если раскомментить **xhr.onload** вместо **xhr.onprogress**, то вдобавок ещё нужно раскомментить на бэке **emitter.complete**, иначе фронт вообще ничего не отображает (т.е. **xhr.onload** показывает инфу только после исполнения **emitter.complete**, на **emitter.send** не реагирует); но не хочется также и на бэке создавать новый эмиттер на каждый вызов, а переиспользвать ранее зарегистрированый. Подозреваю, что на фронте нужно как-то иначе принимать данные, чтобы эта конструкция рационально работала, но в ДЖС я плохо ориентируюсь.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `xhr.abort()`, это рвет соединение, а так же вызов `connect()` заново запускает функцию соединения.

Comment: Я так и пробовал, но без abort этих соединений накапливается целая куча (видно в девтулс, что они висят незакрытыми и ничего не делают).

Comment: Так вам и connect убрать тоже надо из onprogress и onload.

Comment: В таком случае он только один раз отрабатывает и закрывается, а не постоянно "дежурит" на приёме. А мне нужно, чтобы фронт мог принять сколько угодно уведомлений в любое время, пока пользователь не закрыл свою страницу.

Comment: Тогда вам нужен сокет. XMLHttpRequest - запрос отправил, ответ получил, соединение закрыл.

Comment: А такая штука как EventSource подойдёт? Сокет это же вроде двунаправленный канал; тут достаточно только от сервера данные пересылать.

Comment: Если кленту надо слушать сервер, то сокет то что надо. Сервер будет при необходимости отправлять сообщения клиенту. То что канал двунаправленный, это не значит, что надо общаться в двух направлениях. Как чат, сообщение отправлено, ответа может и не быть.